# Изучение JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Ребята, посоветуйте книги для самостоятельного изучения JavaScript.

Comment: В любом процессе изучения львиная доля тратится на привыкание к новому, будь то язык программирования или высшая математика. Нет такой волшебной книги, что прочитав ее, вы станете гуру. По JavaScript можно читать все подряд, пока вы не привыкнете к нему и сами будете в состоянии оценивать полезность той или иной книги для вас.:)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь )